# TextView is not shown

Tags: java, android, textview

Hey my problem is that the content of the textview is not shown no matter if I define it as visible or not. No problems displayed in logcat...

I used the AsyncTask like JFrankie told me but the value of my textview is still not shown whats now the matter? Now i get an logcat error that the socket is closed has it sth to do with this?

Here is my method:

```
  public void fetchUpdate(View view) {
     AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> at= new Task();

    at.execute();
    try {
        tv.setText(at.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

AsyncTask part:

```
   package com.example.s_crewclientprealpha;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import java.io.OptionalDataException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Task extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
     Socket serverside = null;
   InputStream i=null;
   OutputStream o=null;
   Thread t=null;
   Thread update=null;
   Thread txtviewable=null;
   String Restaurant=null;
   String UserID=null;
   String UserBestellung=null;
   CharSequence text=null;
   TextView tv=null;
   ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
   ObjectInputStream ois=null;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    connecttoServer();

    try {
        oos.writeInt(1);
        oos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

        Restaurant=(String) ois.readObject();       
} catch (OptionalDataException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    return Restaurant;

}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){


}


public void connecttoServer(){
     try {
            serverside=new Socket("veteran1.ez.lv",5544);//serverside ist der server
            i= serverside.getInputStream();
            o= serverside.getOutputStream();
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(o);
            ois= new ObjectInputStream(i);
             } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


}
```

}
XML part:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/holzbackground"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewHeadline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/txtdev"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/UsersName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewHeadline"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/usernamebsptxt" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewBottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="89dp"
    android:text="@string/txtview2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/bestellungstext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/UsersName"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/HinttxtOrder"
    android:text="@string/HinttxtOrder" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttontest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bestellungstext"
    android:onClick="setOrder"
    android:text="@string/sendorderbuttontxt" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/updatebutton"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttontest"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttontest"
    android:text="@string/update"
    android:onClick="fetchUpdate" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttontoadminconsole"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/buttontxttoadminconsole"
    android:onClick="toAdminConsole" />
```

Logcat:

```
    11-19 20:07:17.482: W/System.err(11921): java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    11-19 20:07:17.482: W/System.err(11921):    at       libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
    11-19 20:07:17.482: W/System.err(11921):    at  libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:140)
   11-19 20:07:17.482: W/System.err(11921):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
   11-19 20:07:17.482: W/System.err(11921):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
   11-19 20:07:17.482: W/System.err(11921):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
   11-19 20:07:17.482: W/System.err(11921):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
   11-19 20:07:17.482: W/System.err(11921):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
   11-19 20:07:17.482: W/System.err(11921):     at libcore.io.Streams.readSingleByte(Streams.java:41)
   11-19 20:07:17.492: W/System.err(11921):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:236)
   11-19 20:07:17.492: W/System.err(11921):     at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:114)
   11-19 20:07:17.492: W/System.err(11921):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.checkReadPrimitiveTypes(ObjectInputStream.java:405)
   11-19 20:07:17.492: W/System.err(11921):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:770)
   11-19 20:07:17.492: W/System.err(11921):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
   11-19 20:07:17.492: W/System.err(11921):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
  11-19 20:07:17.492: W/System.err(11921):  at com.example.s_crewclientprealpha.Task.doInBackground(Task.java:42)
 11-19 20:07:17.492: W/System.err(11921):   at  com.example.s_crewclientprealpha.Task.doInBackground(Task.java:1)
 11-19 20:07:17.492: W/System.err(11921):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
 11-19 20:07:17.492: W/System.err(11921):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
 11-19 20:07:17.492: W/System.err(11921):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
 11-19 20:07:17.492: W/System.err(11921):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
 11-19 20:07:17.492: W/System.err(11921):   at   
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
 11-19 20:07:17.492: W/System.err(11921):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Are you able to retrieve the text by doing tv.getText().toString() ?

Comment: try something other than Restaurant like "Hi" and see what happens

Comment: calling `Thread.sleep(250);` on the ui thread?

Comment: hi works so i guess it has sth to do with my streams...     yes it is that nobody aborts the sending to the other side through reclicking the button cause the server has to do some work...

Comment: `(String) ois.readObject();` are you sure of that? shouldn't it be `readUTF()` ?

Comment: `protected Void onPostexecute(Result result){` your method declaration is wrong. should be `protected void onPostExecute(Void result){`, and it cannot return anything.

Comment: @njzk Casting to string worked all the time fine for me... Now i changed  the onpostexecute methods return type to a string which returns my string i retrieved from the Server to set it as the text of the textview but it still doesnt show up...

Comment: your onPostexecute method cannot be called because it does not have the correct signature.

Comment: @njzk2 so what Signature should it have ?

Comment: `protected void onPostExecute(Void result){`, given the signature of your asyncTask. Also, add the @Override annotation so the compiler can check the signature is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it can't work because you run the update in a Thread and then the flow continues and when it arrives to the TextView update the value (you should write in the textview) can be null or empty. There's no syncronization between Thread result and the Textview.
You shouldn't use this approach, i suggest to you to use AsyncTask (be careful to the memory leaks) or volley to retrieve remote information and update the TextView.
If you use AsyncTask what you wrote in the thread should go in doInBackground method and the TextView update should go in the onPostExecute method.

Comment: i used async task but now it doesnt update my textview it is only the string of the beginning displayed and not the string i retrieved i´ll post my code to my question above...

Comment: @burnaut - you should post exactly what you did in your original question. It doesn't imply the use of an AsyncTask at all. JFrankie's answer is correct. You are spawning a thread and immediately expecting the result once you call .start() on your thread. start() simply will trigger the thread to run. By the time your thread actually starts your setText(Restaurant) call will already have been performed and Restaurant will always be null.

Comment: @dymmeh thx for your explanation :) I thought the order would be respected by android

Comment: @JFrankie but how should i change the TextView value in the async task class cause if i call i there , the logcat error "only the original thread that created the view hierarchy can touch its views

Comment: In the AsyncTask there're three main methods to override, you are interested on:  protected List<String> doInBackground(String... params) {...} and protected void onPostExecute(String) {} i guess you should have a String as result parameter and pass it the onPostExecute. This string is the result of your background process and you should update the TextView in onPostExecute using this string.